# ios7 AVFoundation performance issues (memory leak)

Tags: ios7, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapture

I am using `AVFoundation` to capture QR codes in my app. In `ios 7.0` I am seeing some major issues with regards to the video capture. The capture takes longer and longer each time i do it, leading the app to crash due to memory leak issues.

It works fine with `ios 7.1`. Is this a known issue?

Comment: iOS7 camera problem on iPhone 4s https://discussions.apple.com/message/24453761#24453761

Comment: I am seeing the issue on iphone 5 though. I was able to resolve the issue...adding the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I had to add the following code when stopping the `captureSession`

```
[_captureSession removeInput:self.captureInput];
```

I am not sure why this didn't present as an issue on ios 7.1 though.